# Use Universal Image Loader for Internal Storage images

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, internal-storage

I have downloaded image from internet to Android and saved it into Internal storage using

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

With that image is save into /data/data/mypackagename/files folder.

Is it possible to use Universal Image Loader to load that image? This is not working for me (myfile = "filename.png").

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("file://"+myfile, myImageVIew);
```

Comment: What is `myfile`? How are you determining its value? BTW, if you are referring to [this library](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), please note that it is no longer being maintained.

Comment: I've edited my question. If not UIL what do you suggest then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) was discontinued a year ago.

> This is not working for me (myfile = "filename.png").

That is not valid path. If you are using `openFileOutput()`, the file will be written to the directory denoted by `getFilesDir()`. So, your image will be in `new File(getFilesDir(), FILENAME)`.

> If not UIL what do you suggest then?

There are dozens of [image-loading libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46). Personally, I use [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso).